# find the infinum of the supremum

Tags: real-analysis

M is the set of all continuous and decreasing functions such that $f(1) = 0$. Find: $$\inf_{f \in M} \sup_{x \in [0;1]} \frac{xf(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}f(t)~\mathrm{d}t}$$

Here is my reasoning: I think that the problem is precisely reduced to the consideration of hyperbola: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, however, it does not satisfy the boundary condition, so consider another function $f(x) = \psi_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{x + \varepsilon} - \frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}$ when $\varepsilon \rightarrow +0$, but I don't understand why this supremum can't be larger, isn't it possible to find such a function that the integral over the segment is very small and then the supremum will be very large?how to prove that the desired infinum is 0 ?

Comment: @Fix sorry, but this is clearly not true

Comment: @Meowdog oh yeah, I read it as both infimums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement is a bit confused, likely due to the edit.

As stated, when looking for the infimum over all functions with the stated restrictions, that infimum is $0$. To prove that, we show that it is non-negative and functions exist which yield an arbitrary small positive value.

Since all values involved in the calculations are nonnegative, the infimum is of course non-negative, that part is easy.

So what needs to be shown is that there a functions $f$ such that $\sup_{x \in [0;1]} \frac{xf(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}f(t)~\mathrm{d}t}$ is smaller than any given positive value.

Your example of $\psi_{\epsilon}(x)$ fulfills that (because the integral in the denominator gets as big as you want if you make), and that concludes the proof.

Sure, there are other functions where $\sup_{x \in [0;1]} \frac{xf(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}f(t)~\mathrm{d}t}$ is bigger, like if you take $f(x)=1-x$, then $xf(x)$ is maximised at $x=\frac12$, so the enumarator of the quotient is $\frac14$, while the denominator is $\frac12$, so $\sup_{x \in [0;1]} \frac{xf(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}f(t)~\mathrm{d}t}$ equals $\frac12$ for $f(x)=1-x$.

But since you want to find the infimum, finding functions where the value is higher isn't relevant!